# allow members to search for chat rooms they belong in XMPP with Smack API

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack, ejabberd

I'm creating a chatroom website were each user can create a room and add his friends to that room and then start chatting!:D I'm using XMPP as the tool for this site with ejabberd server and smack API as client for room configuration! as you've already understood rooms are member only but I'm looking for a way to let each user see all rooms that she is a member of!
is it possible with xmpp protocol(to get all rooms that I'm member of)?how?

Does making the rooms public solve the problem? BTW how can I do it with smack API?
or better say, how can I choose to set a room public or hidden

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible in XMPP. This has been asked before, see: [Is there a way to determine which Mulit User Conferences (MUC) a user has joined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042077/is-there-a-way-to-determine-which-mulit-user-conferences-muc-a-user-has-joined)

You could however keep track of these rooms yourself in a separate data store each time an user would enter (and/or leave) the room, but this is outside the scope of XMPP as mentioned earlier.